# Source: MySql.Data.Entity.EF6 Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, entity-framework-6, mysql.data

Source: MySql.Data.Entity.EF6 stored procedure generate error Index was outside the bounds of the array.

[image]

```
  List<PayRollAllocationList> payroll = db.SP_EmployeePayRoll(orgCode, Medicalallowcode, HouseRentallowcode, HomeLoanInterest, Sect80allowcode, Childallowcode, Mediclaimallowcode, convallowcode, Miscellaneous, fromMonthValue, fromYearValue, toMonthValue, toYearValue, startDateValue, endDateValue)
                .Select(x => new PayRollAllocationList
                {
                    BankAccNo = x.BankAccountNo,
                    BankName = x.BankName,
                    BankIFSCCode = x.BankIFSCCode,
                    estatus = x.Status,
                    PayrollMonth = x.Month,
                    Year = x.Year,
                    EmployeeName = x.EmpoyeeName,
                    Designation = x.Designation,
                    JoiningDate = x.JoiningDate,
                    payconveyance = x.ConveyanceAndInternetReimbursement,
                    PayMedicalAllow = x.MedicalAllowance,
                    PayHouseAllow = x.HouseRentAllowance,
                    PayHomeLoanInterest = x.HomeLoanInterest,
                    PaySectionAllow = x.MonthlyInvestments,
                    Paychildedu = x.ChildrenEducationAllowance,
                    Paymediclaim = x.Mediclaim,
                    ////miscellaneous = db.salarymasters.Where(t => t.ApplicationUserID == x.ApplicationUserID && t.AllowanceTypeID == Miscellaneous && t.IsActive == true && t.applicationuser.organizationmaster.OrganizationCode == orgCode).Select(t => t.Amount) != null ? db.salarymasters.Where(t => t.ApplicationUserID == x.ApplicationUserID && t.AllowanceTypeID == Miscellaneous && t.IsActive == true && t.applicationuser.organizationmaster.OrganizationCode == orgCode).Select(t => t.Amount).Sum() : 0,
                    Paymiscellaneous = x.Miscellaneous,
                    PayBasicSalary = x.Basic,
                    PayIncentive = x.TotalCompensation,
                    PayTDSDeduction = string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.TDS) ? "0" : x.TDS,
                    PayEmployeeESIC = x.EmployeeESIC,
                    PayEmployerESIC = x.EmployerESIC,
                    PayEmployeePF = x.EmployeePF,
                    PayEmployerPF = x.EmployerPF,
                    TotalESIC = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.EmployeeESIC) ? Convert.ToDecimal(x.EmployeeESIC) + (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.EmployerESIC) ? Convert.ToDecimal(x.EmployerESIC) : 0) : 0),
                    TotalPF = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.EmployeePF) ? Convert.ToDecimal(x.EmployeePF) + (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.EmployerPF) ? Convert.ToDecimal(x.EmployerPF) : 0) : 0),
                    PayProfessionalTax = string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.ProfessionalTax) ? "0" : x.ProfessionalTax,
                    PayNonTaxableAmount = x.TotalNonTaxable,
                    PayTaxableAmount = x.TotalTaxableCompensation,
                    PaysalaryandConv = x.SalaryConveyance,
                    Paytotalcompensation = x.TotalCompensation,
                    PayNetSalary = x.NetPayble,
                    PayprojectIncentive = x.ProjectIncentive,
                    PayOTIncentive = x.OTIncentive,
                    PayAdjustAmt = x.AdjustmentAmount,
                    AdjustDesc = x.AdjustmentDescriptiom,
                    PayLWPAmt = x.LWP,
                }).ToList();
```

at MySql.Data.Entity.EFMySqlDataReader.GetDataTypeName(Int32 ordinal)
atSystem.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.BufferedDataRecord.ReadMetadata(String providerManifestToken, DbProviderServices providerServices, DbDataReader reader)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ShapedBufferedDataRecord.Initialize(String providerManifestToken, DbProviderServices providerServices, DbDataReader reader, Type[] columnTypes, Boolean[] nullableColumns)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.BufferedDataReader.Initialize(String providerManifestToken, DbProviderServices providerServices, Type[] columnTypes, Boolean[] nullableColumns)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateFunctionObjectResult[TElement](EntityCommand entityCommand, ReadOnlyCollection`1 entitySets, EdmType[] edmTypes, ExecutionOptions executionOptions)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass45`1.b__44()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass45`1.b__43()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction[TElement](String functionName, ExecutionOptions executionOptions, ObjectParameter[] parameters)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction[TElement](String functionName, MergeOption mergeOption, ObjectParameter[] parameters)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction[TElement](String functionName, ObjectParameter[] parameters)
   at OMS.omsdbEntities.SP_EmployeePayRoll(String orgCode, Nullable`1 medicalallowcode, Nullable`1 houseRentallowcode, Nullable`1 homeLoanInterest, Nullable`1 sect80allowcode, Nullable`1 childallowcode, Nullable`1 mediclaimallowcode, Nullable`1 convallowcode, Nullable`1 miscellaneous, Nullable`1 fromMonthValue, Nullable`1 fromYearValue, Nullable`1 toMonthValue, Nullable`1 toYearValue, Nullable`1 startDateValue, Nullable`1 endDateValue) in F:\Pooja\OMS\OMS\OMS\OMS_data.Context.cs:line 185
   at OMS.Service.ReportService.GetPayRollAllocationList() in F:\Pooja\OMS\OMS\OMS\Service\ReportService.cs:line 132

Comment: Can you try running code by removing all that logic of checking string null and converting to decimal. Just assign value 0 to all those properties and try running

Comment: yes have tried by executing like this var payrollData = db.SP_EmployeePayRoll(orgCode, Medicalallowcode, HouseRentallowcode, HomeLoanInterest, Sect80allowcode, Childallowcode, Mediclaimallowcode, convallowcode, Miscellaneous, fromMonthValue, fromYearValue, toMonthValue, toYearValue, startDateValue, endDateValue); but getting the same error